# What is the correct way to use DB insert with where condition in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to insert data into MYSQL and update if there is already a value there. Can't seem to get the insert statement right. This is what I wrote

```
DB::insert('insert INTO dataentries (MAth) values(?)',[$total])->where('ID_number', $id_numbers);
```

Comment: Why you don't use eloquent?

Comment: Tried that but was unable to use the 'where' condition

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/inserting-if-record-not-exist-updating-if-exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **updateOrCreate** statement. 
Something like this (not tested):

```
$updateOrCreate = App\Dataentries::updateOrCreate(
    ['total' => $value],
    ['id' => $id]
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Use `updateOrCreate()`:

```php
$dataentry = App\Dataentry::updateOrCreate(
    ['ID_number' => $id_number],
    ['MAth' => $total]
);
```